# Convert pandas DataFrame to dict where each value is a list of values of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Let's say I have the DataFrame

```
filename size inverse similarity
123.txt  1    2       34
323.txt  3    1       44
222.txt  4    1       43
```

I want to create a dictionary in the form

```
{'123.txt': [1, 2, 34],
 '323.txt': [3, 1, 44],
 '222.txt': [4, 1, 43]}
```

Solutions I have found deal with the case of creating a dict with single values using something like

```
df.set_index('Filename')['size'].to_dict()
```

Comment: Why not iterate through the dataframe using a dict comprehension? Why are you trying to pull the data to a `dict`?

Comment: Because data structure is not the same thing as DataFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `'filename'` as the index, take the transpose, then use [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='list'`:

```
my_dict = df.set_index('filename').T.to_dict(orient='list')
```

The resulting output:

```
{'323.txt': [3, 1, 44], '222.txt': [4, 1, 43], '123.txt': [1, 2, 34]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach with dict comprehension:

```
{k: v for k, v in zip(df['filename'], df.set_index('filename').values.tolist())}
Out: {'123.txt': [1, 2, 34], '222.txt': [4, 1, 43], '323.txt': [3, 1, 44]}
```